# How to test promise before it runs finally with JEST

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a function like this:

```js
let settings = {
  isRun: false
}
function testPromise(promise) {
  settings.isRun = true;
  return promise.finally(() => settings.isRun = false;)
}
```

How can test isRun = true when run testPromise before finally expression run. I tried with

```js
it('should isRun true when testPromise running', async () => {
   expect(settings.isRun).toBeFalsy();
   await testPromise(Promise.resolve('run')).then(() => {
     expect(settings.isRun).toBeTruthy();
   }
   expect(settings.isRun).toBeFalsy();
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can execute but not wait for the promise to observe the intermittent value change you want to see.

```js
it('should isRun true when testPromise running', () => {
    expect(settings.isRun).toBeFalsy();
    const promise = testPromise(Promise.resolve('run'));
    // At this point, promise is not resolved yet, so the callback in finally has not executed yet.
    expect(settings.isRun).toBeTruthy();
    // If you want to test it changed back to fasle
    promise.then(() => {
        expect(settings.isRun).toBeFalsy();
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this guaranteed to work every time? It's very possible I'm just not familiar enough with how this scenario works, but it looks to me like the promise may sometimes resolve before `expecting` the value `toBeTruthy`.

Comment: @MattU I forgot exactly how javascript's event loop works with promise so I can't explain the why here. Some quick Google search with those key words should shed more light on this. But to answer your question, I think this test passes 100% of the time.

Comment: hey @MattU, I test some cases, it works properly. But I changed a bit. instead of using `then` on the promise, I use `await` on `promise` after that I add `expect(settings.isRun).toBeFalsy()`; but I think using `then` the same @Hanchen code will work

Comment: Fair enough. I'm also not familiar enough to know 100%, but I thought I'd ask anyhow. If it works, great!